# Raphaël Bug : arrow-end

Tags: raphael

I am using Raphaël library to create a quick draw tool.
But there is an error with arrow end, they are assigned same for all lines.

Say,I have lineA with an arrowhead of #raphael-marker-oval. Then, I draw lineB and assign an arrowhead of #raphael-marker-oval also.
Whenever I change the arrowhead of lineA to a new color, the arrowhead of lineB will be changed to same color also.

Please help!!

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: I was looking for info on Raphael `arrow-end` and found this which illustrates the problem: **http://jsfiddle.net/hJ39e/** - each arrowhead should have the same colour as the path it tips, but instead, they both take the colour of the newest path with arrowheads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having a similar problem, where arrowheads disappear when a containing div is hidden. This seems to be a bug in Raphael: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/pull/525 
I'm just researching it and trying to figure out how to fix it ...

Looks like the problem is fixed if markerIds are unique. This is what I did to fix it:
in raphael.js:
Line 28:

```
var raphaelMarkerIdFixCount = 1;
```

Line 5938:
replace this:

```
markerId = "raphael-marker-" + se + type + w + h;
```

with this:

```
markerId = "raphael-marker-" + se + type + w + h + raphaelMarkerIdFixCount;
raphaelMarkerIdFixCount++;
```

Since it now means that a new marker element is created every time, it may lead to memory issues if you are drawing a huge number of arrows - someone may be able to come up with a better patch, this fix is certainly in the 'quick-and-dirty' category - but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. And tried to fix it but it is coming from **`Raphael.js`**

**I am sure it is a bug.** Do not waste your time on it. Maybe you can report it to THEM

Comment: Ok thanks Roma, But do you know any other script, or any other idea to make it work ??